# Evaluate limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ of $\frac{y^2-x \arctan y}{y}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^2-x \arctan y}{y}$$
My attempt: along the direction $(0,y)$ the function is identically $0$, so if the limit exists it is $0$.

So using the fact that $\arctan y=y+\text{o}(y)$ when $y\to0$ and the triangle inequality we have that
$$0\leq\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left|\frac{y^2-x \arctan y}{y}\right|=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|y^2-x \arctan y|}{|y|}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|y^2-xy+\text{o}(xy)|}{|y|}\leq$$
$$\leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|y|^2+|xy|+\text{o}(xy)}{|y|}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left(|y|+|x|+\frac{\text{o}(xy)}{|y|}\right)=0$$
Is this right? I'm not sure about some steps, in particular:

(1) I'm not sure that I can use the triangle inequality if there is $\text{o}(xy)$;

(2) I'm not sure if $\frac{\text{o}(xy)}{|y|}\to0$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Thanks in advance, any reason why this could be wrong and any advices are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangle inequality is OK and $\frac {o(xy)} y$ does tend to $0$ since $\frac y {|y|}$ is bounded and $x \to 0$. However I suggest the following better approach:

Split it as $\lim [y-\frac {x \arctan y}  y]$. Since the first term has limit $0$ you only have to look for the limit of $\frac {x \arctan y}  y$. Using the fact that $\frac  {\arctan y} y \to 1$ as $ y\to 0$ we see that the limit of $\frac {x \arctan y}  y$ is $(0)(1)=0$. Hence the answer is $0$.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my original message, I've edited it.

Comment: @ZaWarudo I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: oh, it was easier than I've made it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

By the triangle inequality

$$\left|\frac{y^2-x \arctan y}{y}\right|\le\left|y\right|+\left|\frac{x\arctan y}{y}\right|$$

where $\left|y\right|\to 0$. Then observe that
$$
\left|\arctan u\right|\leq|u|, \quad  |u|\leq1,
$$ so, switching to polar coordinates with $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta,r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, as $r\to 0$, you get

> $$
> \left|\frac{x \arctan y}{y}\right|=\left|\frac{r\cos\theta \arctan (r\sin\theta)}{r\sin\theta}\right|\leq \left|\frac{r\cos\theta ~r\sin\theta}{r\sin\theta}\right|\leq r.
> $$

The sought limit is equal to $0$.